# Capture before update and deleted records in separate table while doing incremental load using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to do an incremental load using merge statement in SQL Server. But I have an added requirement to capture records which are deleted & records which are updated in a different table.

After the merge statement I added `@output` statement to capture modified records.

Current table

```
empname department
------------------
TJ       CSE
RN       MECH
```

After update and delete

```
empname department
------------------
TJ       ECE
```

Capture modified records in different table

```
empname  department Action
-----------------------------
TJ        CSE       Updated
RN        MECH      Deleted
```

Comment: you can use trigger.

Comment: @mkRabbani could you pleasehelp me how can i do that.

Comment: please refer to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @user11894930 . . . I don't understand.  If you have an `output` clause, then you should have the information you need.  You should show your current code (perhaps in a simplified form).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a trigger that will capture modified entries.

For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Your_Table_Trigger_Name
   ON  Your_Table
   AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
```

Then write your query. The updated data will be available in the `inserted` table that is available in the context of your trigger, which you can then treat like any regular table. The same goes for the deleted data but it will be available in the `deleted` table.

Example:

if you update data in your table:

```
update Your_Table
set Column_A = null
```

this will now be available via:

```
select * from inserted
```

and deleted data:

```
delete from Your_Table
```

will then be available via:

```
select * from deleted
```